# If pattern repeats two times (nonconsecutive) match both patterns, regex

Tags: regex

I have 3 values that I'm trying to match. `foo`, `bar` and `123`. However I would like to match them only if they can be matched twice.

In the following line:

```
foo;bar;123;foo;123;
```

since `bar` is not present twice, it would only match:

`foo`;bar;`123`;`foo`;`123`;

I understand how to specify to match exactly two matches, `(foo|bar|123){2}` however I need to use backreferences in order to make it work in my example.
I'm struggling putting the two concepts together and making a working solution for this.

Comment: Which programming language do you use? It might be easier to split on the semicolon and use sth. like `if ... in ...`

Comment: I'm unclear what you're asking: are you trying to find which words appear twice? Is a word a match if it appears more than twice?

Comment: @Jan I'm tied to an old Oracle software and I can only paste in the regex as an option in a box.

Comment: @glennjackman I'm trying to find only the words that appear twice, I only have words that appear once or twice. I want to mach both words and replace them, which will leave only the words that do not appear twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use

```
(?<=^|;)([^\n;]+)(?=.*(?:(?<=^|;)\1(?=;|$)))
```

---

Broken down, this is

```
(?<=^|;)         # pos. loobehind, either start of string or ;
([^\n;]+)        # not ; nor newline 1+ times
(?=.*            # pos. lookahead
    (?:
        (?<=^|;) # same pattern as above
        \1       # group 1
        (?=;|$)  # end or ;
     )
)

\b       # word boundary
([^;]+)  # anything not ; 1+ times
\b       # another word boundary
(?=.*\1) # pos. lookahead, making sure the pattern is found again
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/ck7LDZ/4).

---

Otherwise - as said in the comments - split on the `;` programmatically and use some programming logic afterwards.

Find a demo in `Python`  for example (can be adjusted for other languages as well):

```
from collections import Counter

string = """
foo;bar;123;foo;123;
foo;bar;foo;bar;
foo;foo;foo;bar;bar;
"""

twins = [element
        for line in string.split("\n")
        for element, times in Counter(line.split(";")).most_common()
        if times == 2]
print(twins)
```

Comment: an up for the "use programming logic" idea.. this doesn't sound like something regex *should* be handling.

Comment: Alternatively (assuming other word boundaries may be present such as a space and that lookbehinds are possible in your engine), you can use `(?:^|(?<=;))([^;]+);(?=.*;(\1;))`. But I do agree, splitting on `;` is a **much** better idea.

Comment: Try that with `foo;bar;123;myfoo;123;`

Comment: @MarcoLuzzara: Now have a look.

Comment: @Jan I prefer https://regex101.com/r/ck7LDZ/6 and even more https://regex101.com/r/ck7LDZ/7 mmmm

Comment: @ctwheels: Lovely :)

Comment: @Jan according to [Regular-Expressions.info](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) it's supported by PCRE 7.2+, PHP 5.2.2+, Java 8+, JGsoft engine 2+. Some languages only match vertical tab characters (instead of vertical whitespace characters, i.e. [C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference), [JavaScript](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_regexp_vtab.asp)) and some match literal `v` character.

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/ck7LDZ/6 is exactly what I am looking for. Now I just have to check if the legacy software I use can handle it

Answer (score 1):

making sure to allow room for text that may occur in between matches with a ".*", this should match any of your values that occur at least twice:

```
(foo|bar|123).*\1
```

Comment: What about `foo;bar;foo;bar;`?

Comment: sorry that will not work as I do not want to match the semicolons